# Typo don't click this Q

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to hide a div if nothing is entered or if something is entered and deleted. What am I doing wrong? I am new to jQuery, thanks.

index.js.erb:

```
if($('#headersearch').val() ==  "") {
    ("#header_user_list").hide()}
else if($('#headersearch').val() !=  "") {
    $("#header_user_list").html('<%= j render @header_users %>')};
```

view:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', :class => "navbar-search", id: "user_header_search_form", style: "margin-left: 90px;" do %>
  <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Find People", :class => "search-query", id: "headersearch" %>
<% end %>
<ul class="users" id="header_user_list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#headersearch').val() ==  "") {
    $("#header_user_list").hide()}
else if($('#headersearch').val() !=  "") {
    $("#header_user_list").html('<%= j render @header_users %>')};
```

hey check u have missed $() in second line....

Comment: Thanks ill take that as a sign to call it a day lol..ill delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Updated**

```
<script>
    $('#headersearch').on('keyup',function(){
        if($(this).val() ==  "") {
            $("#header_user_list").hide()
        }// add $ before selector
        else {// remove if condition from here
            $("#header_user_list").html('<%= j render @header_users %>');
            // You should use ajax here
        };

    });
</script>
```

Comment: @rohan_kumar thanks, any idea why it hides the div for good? even when I type again the div doesnt come back

Comment: @APJ test the above I have made changes in it.

Comment: @rohan_kumar hm still no luck on making the div reappear. seems hide is getting rid of it for good

Comment: I just replaced hide with html('') and it works. Do you know how to do the same thing if the searchbar isnt active with a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery `.change()` method and/or `.keyup()` event listeners then check if the value in the field is empty, and if it is then hide the element. You can use multiple listeners on the same element if you want to make sure you've covered all bases.